# Can't authenticate in Spring LDAP

Tags: java, spring, authentication, active-directory, spring-ldap

I use win server 2003 with AD. And want to connect via Spring LDAP.
An error occurs when I try to connect to `http://localhost:8090/`:

```
2017-05-19 22:48:46.768 ERROR 18868 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at hello.ldap.client.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at hello.HelloController.index(HelloController.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
<...>
```

Code from [baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-ldap)

**LdapClient**

```
package hello.ldap.client;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.*;
import org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapNameBuilder;

import javax.naming.Name;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;

public class LdapClient {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ContextSource contextSource;

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public void authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
        contextSource.getContext("cn=" + username + ",cn=users," + env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.partitionSuffix"), password);
    }

    public List<String> search(final String username) {
        return ldapTemplate.search(
          "cn=users",
          "cn=" + username,
          (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> (String) attrs
          .get("cn")
          .get());
    }

    public void create(final String username, final String password) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
          .newInstance()
          .add("cn", "users")
          .add("cn", username)
          .build();
        DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", digestSHA(password));

        ldapTemplate.bind(context);
    }

    public void modify(final String username, final String password) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
          .newInstance()
          .add("ou", "users")
          .add("cn", username)
          .build();
        DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", digestSHA(password));

        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
    }

    private String digestSHA(final String password) {
        String base64;
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            digest.update(password.getBytes());
            base64 = Base64
              .getEncoder()
              .encodeToString(digest.digest());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "{SHA}" + base64;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig**

```
package hello.ldap.javaconfig;

import hello.ldap.client.LdapClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "hello.ldap.*" })
@Profile("default")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.partitionSuffix"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.principal"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapClient ldapClient() {
        return new LdapClient();
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 8090
ldap.partitionSuffix=dc=GRSU,dc=local
ldap.partition=GRSU
ldap.principal=cn=Jack Wood,cn=users
ldap.password=1234
ldap.port=389
ldap.url=ldap://192.168.56.101
```

Start point
**App**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**HelloController**

```
package hello;

import hello.ldap.client.LdapClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        LdapClient ldapClient = new LdapClient();
        ldapClient.authenticate("Jack Wood", "1234");
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

AD structure.

[image: AD]

Application structure

[image: Application structure]

As I understand problem in `contextSource`. How can I fix?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would personally not trust baeldung as a valid tutorial site. Their practices are often a bit sketchy. This is my own opinion.

Comment: @kkflf What tutorial for Spring LDAP can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

You have not initiated your spring application. This is the starting point of spring, without initializing nothing work will.
You will have to add something like this to your main method:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

and add the following annotation(If you are using springboot):

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to fix it, but the error remained. Updated the topic, look, please.

Comment: You should look at this tutorial instead:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Comment: Maybe you can help with [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084343/spring-ldap-and-spring-boot-configuration)?

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to define a subdomain in your partitionSuffix:

Original:

```
ldap.partitionSuffix=dc=GRSU,dc=local
```

Correct:

```
ldap.partitionSuffix=ou=Users,dc=GRSU,dc=local
```

[image]