# Spring LDAP and Spring Boot configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

I have educational problem:

There are virtual machine with windows server 2003 (AD) with users and their passwords. Connection to the machine is established (ip:192.168.56.101:389).

The purpose of the web application is to enable the user to change his password in AD.

Problem: can't configure connection to windws server 2003.

I started from this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

When I try to log in as "Jack Wood" and pass "1234" I got error.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: 
Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; 
nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: 
[LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece ]; remaining name 'cn=Jack Wood,cn=Users'
```

[image: Error]

**Please check `application.properties`.**

```
#spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif
#spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
#spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
spring.ldap.base=dc=GRSU,dc=local
spring.ldap.urls=192.168.56.101:389
spring.ldap.username=cn=Jack Wood,cn=Users,dc=GRSU,dc=local
spring.ldap.password=1234
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.LdapShaPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},cn=Users")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://192.168.56.101:389/");
    }

}
```

**HomeController**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Welcome to the home page!";
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image: AD structure]

Comment: I do not have that much experience with LDAP. You should however not both configure `application.properties` and `WebSecurityConfig`. Either one should be enough for `Spring Boot`. Seems like `groupSearchBase` and `spring.ldap.base` are different? Why are you using credentials in your `application.properties`? Is anonymous mode enabled for the LDAP server user lookup seach?

Comment: Did you got solution for this problem.?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
spring.ldap.username=cn=Jack Wood,cn=Users,dc=GRSU,dc=local
```

to

```
spring.ldap.username=cn=Jack Wood,cn=Users
```

Does that help?

My understanding is that the username uses the relative domain name (rdn) as opposed to the absolute domain name (dn).